# Decoding burp XSS DNS resolution payload

Tags: xss, burp-suite, owasp

I'm testing `burp` against a vulnerable application as part of work for my client. There was one successful xss payload related to `DNS lookup` which worked on `form data` at point of file-upload. Here is the part of `payload`

```
javascript:/*</script><img/onerror='-/"/-/ onmouseover=1/-/[`*/[]/[(new(Image)).src=(/;/+/7mu0war5msdjnc8auyu75qw2ntttht9h18p0cs0hX;.burpcollaborator.net/).replace(/.;/g,[])]//'src=>
------WebKitFormBoundaryvITwh4thvzw75H3d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"
```

The response is as as [image: attached]

I want help in deciphering of payload because it seems quite convoluted.
`<img/onerror='-/"/-/`
This is believe causing img tag to fail causing event-handler `onerror` to trigger but I don't understand the use of `'-/"/-/`

`` onmouseover=1/-/[`*/[]/ ``

Similary, as error popups the `victim` moves his move over and this in return kicks of another event/action which is including src tag and loading external content which is replace with a regex like whatever is in `src` tag is replace with output of DNS resolution

I appreciate if someone can decode piece by piece how this payload is actually crafted thanks.